# If $\frac{dr}{dt}=c\times r(t)$, for $c$ a constant vector, then $r(t)$ describes a particular circle

Tags: geometry

> Suppose the curve $r=r(t)$ satisfies $\frac{dr}{dt}=c\times r(t)$, where $c$ is a constant vector. Show that the curve is the circle in which the plane through $r(0)$ normal to $c$ intersects a sphere with radius $|r(0)|$ centered at the origin.

Can somebody help me with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

Let $\vec r(0) = \vec a$ (which is also a constant).
Very convenient vector forms of the equations of plane and sphere are:

$$ \vec r \cdot \vec c = const = \vec a \cdot \vec c $$
for a plane to which the point $\vec r = \vec a$ belongs; and

$$ \vec r \cdot \vec r = r^2 = const = a^2  = \vec a \cdot \vec a$$
for a sphere of radius $a = |\vec a|$. To prove that each point of the curve is in the plane, dot the curve's differential equation with $\vec c$:

$$ \vec c \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt} = \vec c \cdot (\vec c \times \vec r) = 0$$
but the left-hand-side is identical to $d(\vec c \cdot \vec r)/dt$ because $\vec c$ is a constant and can be taken inside the derivative. Integrating it, we see that 
 $\vec c \cdot \vec r$ is a constant on the curve. In other words, every point on the curve has the same $\vec c \cdot \vec r$ as the point $\vec r(0)$, for which it is exactly $\vec a \cdot \vec c$. Thus each point also satisfies the equation of the plane, i.e. the curve is a subset of the plane.

To show the same with the sphere, dot the equation with $\vec r$ instead:
$$ \vec r \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt} = \vec r \cdot (\vec c \times \vec r) = 0$$
as in the case of the plane, a vector identity transforms the left-hand side into $(1/2)d(\vec r \cdot \vec r)/dt$, so after integration,  $\vec r \cdot \vec r$ is also a constant on the curve, and for the point $\vec r(0)$ its value is exactly $\vec a \cdot \vec a$. Hence every point satisfies the equation of the sphere as well, i.e. the curve is a subset of the sphere.

The converse, that every point of the intersection of the plane and sphere belongs to the curve, can be proven with a more brute force approach, but I like the following way of thinking about it:

If we think of $t$ as time, then $d\vec r/dt$ is a velocity (of say, a particle traversing the curve). You can show that as a vector function of time, it is continuous, and its magnitude is everywhere a constant finite non-zero value. This means the particle never stops, never suddenly changes direction (therefore cannot double back), and for long enough time will travel an arbitrarily long distance. Therefore it must travel along the whole circle.

Comment: Whenever you said to dot the equations you always also differentiated. Can you explain why?

Comment: I mean dot the equation of the curve, it's a differential equation, the derivative is already in it. I just wrote an equivalent expression on the far left of the line, because from there we see the constant-ness of the respective dot product

Comment: In your first step shouldn't you be doing c dot r(t) instead of c dot r'(t)?

Comment: I edited it, maybe it's a bit clearer now. I start with $dr/dt = c \times r$ and dot that with $c$ for the plane and with $r$ for the sphere.

Comment: My question is why are you considering the equation of the curve as dr/dt when it is just r(t)?

Comment: I don't have an explicit equation for the curve. It is defined by the equation it satisfies, which contains $dr/dt$ (llok at the first sentence of your problem).

Comment: Why are you dotting the curve's differential equation instead of it's real equation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66452/discussion-between-nick-pavlov-and-faiq-raees).